# How to keep background aspect ratio with CSS3 scale?

Tags: css, animation, transform, scale

I would like to animate the width of a container with multiple divs using CSS3 transitions. Each child has a `background` and a property `background-size: cover`.

I prefer to use CSS3 `scale` rather than `width` for better performances. But with `scale` the background doesn't keep its `aspect ratio`.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mw29obpa/1/) showing the problem.

Is it possible to keep aspect ratio?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible using `scale`.

You see, the thing is when you use `width` to scale the div it forces the browser to do some math for the element and an entire box model, it doeas the layout of the CSS and repaints and rerenders it entirely.

When you use `scale` it moves your element to a separate layer and it doesn't recalculate anything, it's just the GPU that processes your element in a very "graphical" way, so scaling 0,5 is just shrinking it visually and thats it. This is the reasony why, as you said, CSS transform is better in terms of performance - because it doesn't recalculate things, but there are some drawbacks of using those transform as you can see. Since it deosn't do the math, it cannot do background-size: cover because there is just not enaugh information to know how to paint it.

Or, let me put it this way: if you do `width: 50%` browser calculates the width of the element and knows it - thanks to that information it can position your background the way you want (and you want it to `cover` so its doing the math, taking the width, height, you background image size etc.).

If you do `scale` it doesn't know the width of the element in terms of CSS layout, it doesn't even care. It just knows how wide it was initialy (visually), renders the layer and than just shrinks it down without any further processing whatsoever. And since its GPU doing that, it's really really fast.